# Branch predictor friendly tree traversal

Tags: algorithm, performance, binary-search-tree, cpu-architecture, branch-prediction

I have an AVL tree and I need to traverse it in ascending and descending order.
I implemented a simple algorithm, where knowing the tree size in advance, I allocate an array and assign `0` to a counter, then I traverse the tree as follows:

```
void traverseAscending(Node cur) {
    if(cur.left != null) traverseAscending(cur.left);
    outVals[totOuts] = cur.data;
    totOuts++;
    if(cur.right != null) traverseAscending(cur.right);
}
```

This is the classics we've all been taught. However, it's slow likely because the branches are mispredicted all the time.

How to traverse the tree in a way friendly for branch predictor?

UPDATE: answering the comments,

1. I came to the conclusion that it's branching that is slow because I profiled the application.
2. The cache should not be an issue because I have multiple relatively small trees that fit the cache.
3. Indeed, the share of this method in the profiler decreases over time, but I would think it's because the algorithm changes so the bottlenecks change. The first ~10 minutes of running this method takes ~6% of the runtime.

Comment: Is it copying the node on every function invocation? Have you tried passing it by reference? Also, where are the array and the counter actually stored, this doesn't look like a nested function?

Comment: @AndreyTyukin, it's Java, so everything is passed by reference. The array and the counter are stored in the object accessed via `this` reference.

Comment: Can you rearrange your tree beforehand? If not, I don't think there's a general solution, since the depths of two consecutive leaves can always differ by one of three values (-1, 0, or 1).

Comment: How did you come to the conclusion that branch prediction is to blame - did you profile it?

Comment: This code isn't slow, but an iterative version could be a bit faster.  Either way, the time is probably dominated by memory access to the node objects.  Most likely you measured it before the JIT compiler could finish optimizing it.

Comment: @MattTimmermans and "Internal Server Error", I've addressed your questions in an update to the post.

Comment: Every branch is travelled once (recursive call) and a second time (returning from recursion). It is impossible to do the traversal without visiting all edges... This is O(n).